# Error in serializaion of Hibernate DTO using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Trying to serialize a DTO to JSON using GSON in my JAVA code.
The DTO extends an abstract class and also implements java.io.Serializable. The DTO as one of its member has a protected String [][] (2 dimensional array)

Getting the following error and have found no legible help so far.

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy. Forgot to register a type adapter?
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:62)
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:59)
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.write(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:93)
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
                at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
                at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:546)
                at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:525)
                at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:480)
                at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:460)

Any help in getting it explained or resolved is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that when you try to serialize a Hibernate DTO, it could not be the same object that you declare at first. Hibernate will write a Proxy class based on your DTO but with different fields to do persistence related operations. So, if your DTO participates in any hibernate operation it will not be your DTO but a proxy. You should copy the contents of the object in a new plain DTO before trying to serialize it.
You can test this by printing the object getClass() method output, it will be a proxy object and GSON don't know how to serialize some proxy fields.
Hope this helps.